# How to Upload Form Data Into a Child Table With Foreign Key

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that should insert data into a child table. The table has a foreign key (`ADD FOREIGN KEY(userid) REFERENCES users(userid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;`) that points to a parent table.
How do I insert the form data and the foreign key at the same time when a user hits submit? So far the foreign key is working and it's all that I get inserted in the child table.
Here's my form:

```
session_start();
require_once('classes/auth.php');
require_once('includes/connect.php');

$user=$_SESSION['SESS_USERID'];

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] =="POST") {
}
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$place=$_POST['place'];
$overmij=$_POST['overmij'];

// Working like clockwork now
$sql = "INSERT INTO userinfo(firstname,lastname,place,overmij,userid)
VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$place','$overmij','$user') ";

// I don't need this because the userid is already in the SESSION
//$sql = "INSERT INTO userinfo (userid) SELECT userid FROM users WHERE //userid='$user'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: What error are you getting (the sql error)? Start with debugging your SQL statement using MySQL Workbench or a similar tool.

Comment: Please go slow, I'm very new to all this...I want to know the syntax for inserting both the formdata and the foreign key into the child table when a user hits submit. I can't find anywhere how to do that. Something is wrong with the syntax, that's all the error I get.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). As for your second insert, use `last_insert_id()`.

Comment: As mentioned above, your code has some serious vulnerabilities; however, your main issue is that you're overriding the $sql variable.  It's just going to run the userid insert in the query.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. Downloaded Workbench but I run system 6.8 on Mac and it doesn't work on an old Mac version....

Comment: Yes, Versalle88. I know and that is the only part that is working. But how do I solve that? Is there anyone with an example or a link with an explanation how to make the code working? Thanks. The thing is that I know what is wrong, but I don't know how to make it right.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `$sql` is not being executed. It is overridden and then the second one is being executed. Have the first one execute as well.

```
// This is not working
$sql = "INSERT INTO userinfo(firstname,lastname,place,overmij)
VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$place','$overmij') ";

/** EXECUTE YOUR QUERY HERE AS WELL **/
//  $conn->query($sql)

// The following is working:
$sql = "INSERT INTO userinfo (userid) SELECT userid FROM users WHERE userid='$user'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment below, you get the following error:

```
 INSERT INTO userinfo(firstname,lastname,place,overmij VALUES ('vsdvsdvds','vdsvdsv','ddv','dvdvdv','cscsc','overmij')
```

There is a missing paranthesis, `)`, before `VALUES`.

**EDIT 2:**

Based on your second comment below:

You are not adding the `userid` in your insert query. You say you already have the `userid` in your session.

And yes, you are right. You don't need to two queries. You can do it one, like the following:

```
INSERT INTO userinfo(userid, firstname,lastname,place,overmij) VALUES ('USERID_FROM_SESSION', 'vsdvsdvds','vdsvdsv','ddv','dvdvdv','cscsc','overmij')
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but the effect it has is that I get 2 rows added in the child table with only the userid. I already found out that the 2nd query  is not necessary because the userid is already in the SESSION. After removing the second query I get the following message:   Error: INSERT INTO userinfo(firstname,lastname,place,overmij VALUES ('vsdvsdvds','vdsvdsv','ddv','dvdvdv','cscsc','overmij') 
You have an error in your SQL syntax near'overmij)' at line 2

Comment: @TimiaBreederveld based on the sql yo provide in the above comment, you are missing a closing `'` in the twitter value

Comment: Yes, thanks, I found that out already. Now I get this   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`membership`.`userinfo`, CONSTRAINT `userinfo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `users` (`userid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (after removing the 2nd query)

Comment: When I activate the 2nd query again I get one row added in the child table with only the userid and the autoincrement of the PK skips a number.

Comment: @TimiaBreederveld, see EDIT 2 in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks kRiZ that did the trick!! Jippie, the problem is SOLVED!!!! I added the userid in the first query and the value of the first query as $user. Now all is working fine. THANKS EVERYONE!!! Now I can worry about security :-)